# How to convert a Date column with lubridate and keep it within the dataframe?

Tags: r, lubridate

Currently, I am trying to change my date column that is stored as a character type into a date type. I am successfully able to use lubridate to make this change. However, it eliminates my data frame and only keeps the new dates as values.

How can I keep everything contained in the data frame?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntgiF.png)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please don't share data or code as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your entire data frame with the value for the newly created date column.

Instead do

```
dc.crime.complete$Date <- ymd(dc.crime.complete$Date)
```

This will overwrite your date column with the new values.